# Typescript cannot find module error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I just converted my react native project to typescript. I had imports for my custom components like this:

```
import Section from "apc";
```

This worked fine since I had a package.json file in my components folder which contained

```
{
  "name": "apc",
  "version":"0.1",
  "description": "My custom components",
  "main": "./Section"
}
```

But after converting the project to typescript and renaming the files to .tsx, I'm getting a red underline in VS Code saying [TS] cannot find module 'apc'

The project runs fine though. I can see correct output in the my emulator. Any way I can hint VS Code to pick up the name from package.json?

Converting the import to a relative path as follows works fine

```
import Section from "./src/Section";
```

Thanks